# jquery-ui chatbox stuck on sending a message

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have decided to use :

http://reason.cs.illinois.edu/wenpu1/chatbox.html

In a grails chat plugin, the functionality was working until I decided to make it open a pop up on user screen and am stuck on how to transmit message sent from primary popup to secondary

so far usera hovers over userb's username and clicks on send pm  - this opens the box and transmits message fine ( i.e. old functionality was to send pm on main screen but only to user - no issues there)

The change is to pop open a pm window and show message and allow user to interact back - it does pop it open but I think I need to write extra stuff which I have sort of called pm: inside the js below... just unsure how to get that pm to appear on the poped up box....

https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-wschat-plugin/blob/master/web-app/js/jquery.ui.chatbox.js

So I guess I need to add pm: to this file:
https://github.com/dexterpu/jquery.ui.chatbox/blob/master/jquery.ui.chatbox.js

does anyone knows what I am on about and how I can update the box with the message?

```
 function sendPM(receiver,sender,pm) {
$(function(event, ui) {
var box = null;
if(box) {
box.chatbox("option", "boxManager").toggleBox();
}else {
box = $("#"+sender).chatbox({id:receiver,
user:{key : "value"},
title : "PM: "+receiver,
messageSent : function(id, user, msg) {
          //$("#log").append(id + " said: " + msg + "<br/>");
           $("#"+suser).chatbox("option", "boxManager").addMsg(id, msg);
          webSocket.send("/pm "+suser+","+msg);
},
pm : function(sender, user, pm) {
//$("#log").append(id + " said: " + msg + "<br/>");
$("#"+sender).chatbox("option", "boxManager").addMsg(id, pm);
//webSocket.send("/pm "+suser+","+msg);
}})
}
});
}
```

Comment: never mind its sorted now